# Sort array `B` given array `A` while keeping some elements intact

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array `A` that serves as a based to sort array `B`, however, I would like to preserve the position of an element in `B` if it doesn't exist in array `A`.

```
$A = array (
  0 => 'Peter',
  1 => 'John',
  2 => 'Mike',
  3 => 'Josh',
  4 => 'Bob',
  5 => 'Jan'
);

$B = array (
   0 => array ('name' => 'Aaron'),
   1 => array ('name' => 'Adam'),
   2 => array ('name' => 'Bob'),
   3 => array ('name' => 'Jan'),
   4 => array ('name' => 'John'),
   5 => array ('name' => 'Matt'),
   6 => array ('name' => 'Mike'),
   7 => array ('name' => 'Peter'),
);
```

so `B` would become after sorting it based on `A`

```
$B = array (
   0 => array ('name' => 'Aaron'), // keep position since is not in `A`
   1 => array ('name' => 'Adam'),  // keep position since is not in `A`
   2 => array ('name' => 'Peter'), // move it up since is first pos in `A`
   3 => array ('name' => 'John'),  
   4 => array ('name' => 'Mike'),
   5 => array ('name' => 'Bob'),
   6 => array ('name' => 'Jan'),
   7 => array ('name' => 'Matt'),
);
```

How can I do sort it like this?

Comment: Are you wanting your solution in PHP? Or are you wanting an algorithm.

Comment: Can you be sure all elements in A will be present in B?

Comment: @RyanDawkins: a PHP solution would be ideal. However an algorithm works too.

Comment: @Pitchinnate: No, elements in A might not be in B, and elements in B might not be in A

Comment: Why did Matt move in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your example is wrong and Matt wasn't suppose to move this works (I just used lowercase letters for `$A` and `$B`:

```
$b_names = array();
foreach($b as $val) {
    $b_names[] = $val['name'];
}
$a_counter = 0;
foreach($b as $key => $val) {
    if(in_array($val['name'],$a)) {
        while(!in_array($a[$a_counter], $b_names)) {
            $a_counter++;
        }
        $b[$key]['name'] = $a[$a_counter];
        $a_counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, Matt wasn't suppose to move. This works great! Thanks.